# Is there a difference between "MK9" and "MK: Komplete Edition"?

Tags: version-differences, mortal-kombat-9, mortal-kombat-komplete-edition

I just want to know if there's some feature that is only in console version, or if it is all the same content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortal_Kombat_%282011_video_game%29#Komplete_Edition):

> On January 9, 2012, Warner Bros Interactive Entertainment announced Mortal Kombat: Komplete Edition. This version was released for Xbox 360 and PlayStation 3 on February 28, 2012 in North America and on March 2 in the United Kingdom, and consists of the **game with all of the downloadable content** released for it. The North American release also includes download codes for the album Mortal Kombat: Songs Inspired by the Warriors, as well as the 1995 film Mortal Kombat (available via PlayStation Store or Xbox Live)

So, `Komplete Edition` has 4 extra characters([Skarlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skarlett#Skarlet), [Rain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rain_%28Mortal_Kombat%29#Rain), [Kenshi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenshi) and [Freddy Krueger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freddy_Krueger)) and some extra skins(like classic ninja skins).

P.S. Don't forget, that `PS3` version of `MK9`(and `Komplete Edition` too ofc) has an exclusive character: [Kratos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kratos_%28God_of_War%29).

Comment: In my experience on PC, all character skins were unlocked from the get-go, even those that, according to the Internet, were supposed to be rewards for quest progression. That's a small downside to the all-inclusivity, in the sense that rewards are devalued.